# Getting WA in SPOJ INCSEQ - Increasing Subsequences

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I dont know why i am getting WA on 10th case , 
I used BIT and Combination.
Problem link : [SPOJ INCSEQ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INCSEQ/)

Problem Details : Given a sequence of N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10,000) integers S1, ..., SN (0 ≤ Si < 100,000), compute the number of increasing subsequences of S with length K (1 ≤ K ≤ 50 and K ≤ N); that is, the number of K-tuples i1, ..., iK such that 1 ≤ i1 < ... < iK ≤ N and Si1 < ... < SiK.

Here is [My Code](https://ideone.com/doQLl9)

I think there is problem with nCr using Mod function. 
   They dont give failing test cases , so i dont have any failing test case.

```
// Here i compute nCk
unsigned long long combination(ll n,ll k)
{
    unsigned long long ans=1;
    k=k>n-k?n-k:k;
    ll j=1;
    for(; j<=k; j++,n--)
    {
        if(n%j==0)
        {
            ans*=n/j;
        }
        else if(ans%j==0)
        {
            ans=ans/j*n;
        }
        else
        {
            ans=(ans*n)/j;
        }
    }
    return ans%mod;
}
```

plz help

Comment: Please provide an example of a failing test case, plus a brief explanation what your algorithm is doing in a nutshell. You should also provide only the part of the code that is connected to the problem, if any of it is redundant. Without these details your question will be closed as "Off topic", because "Why isn't my code working?" questions are off topic without reasonable explanation.

Comment: Your `combination` is wrong, because for large number, the result of nCr will be bigger than `long long` range.

Comment: number will be max n<=1000 k<=1000.
what should i do ? should i mod value ? @PhamTrung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `combination` method is wrong, because for large number, the result of nCr will be bigger than `long long` range.

So , using modulus efficiently, we can avoiding overflow in this situation

We know that there is another way to calculate  nCr

we know that

```
nCr = (n - 1)C(r - 1) + (n - 1)Cr
```

And as k <= 50 which is small, we can calculate our combination table `c` as follow:

```
int[][]c = new int[n + 1][k+1];
c[0][0] = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    c[i][0] = 1;
    if(i <= k)
        c[i][i] = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
        c[i][j] = c[i - 1][j - 1] + c[i - 1][j];
        c[i][j] %= mod;
    }
}
```

The mod operation will make sure that our result will never get overflow.